Why does BART-base model automatically truncate the output?
I was fine-tuning a BART[base] model to perform the translation task. My input sentence has 126 tokens, and after being processed by the fine-tuned model, the input_ids has 129 ids. In the end, when I use tokenizer.decode to try to convert ids to tokens, it significantly truncates most of the output, because the output only has 63 tokens. No matter how I change the input sentence, the input_ids always remain 129 ids, and the output sentence is still truncated as well.
Here's my code:
checkpoint = r"E:\checkpoint\bart-wmt17\checkpoint-5368000"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
sentence1 = "Machine learning has gained a lot of attention due to its massive success in various domains, and natural language processing  is one of them. Recently, deep learning has significantly improved the performance of NLP models for multiple tasks to almost human-like performance. However, this came at the cost of a significant increase in the required resources for computational power and needed datasets.    As a result, diverse training paradigms have been proposed to alleviate the need for enormous computational resources, such as training models with multiple parties.    Similarly, data is being crawled from the internet to alleviate the need for large datasets."
inputs= tokenizer([sentence1],return_tensors="pt", max_length=256, truncation=True)
ot = model.generate(**inputs, max_length=256)
encode = ot.reshape(-1)
output = tokenizer.decode(encode, max_length=1024, skip_special_tokens=True)

The output sentence should not be truncated.
